# Getting less than expected results using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, json, web-services, facebook-graph-api

i am getting post or feed results using the webservice

```
$jsonStr = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbName.'/posts?access_token='.$accessToken.'&limit=30');
```

what I notice though is that if I set the limit to 30.. i seem to get about two results.
if i set to 500, i will get maybe.. 80?  and the load time will be significantly longer.  Is this because it's only showing me the public posts but querying all of them?  I would like to show as many posts as possible while keeping the load time to a minimum..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Graph API uses paging for the bigger results. You should read about the paging API of the Facebook Graph API. Most of the case, because of the paging , facebook API returns fewer results.

[Facebook Graph API Paging](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/)